# var (taken from a xml file, with a javascript) in a < a href=

Tags: javascript, jquery

I repost the question (i deleted what i did before, because, my fault, i was not enough clear, i'm deeply sorry).

I have this var:

```
var telefono = $(this).find('Telefono').text();
```

This "Telefono" is a number, taken from a xml file, with a javascript.
I don't post all the function, but if you think it helps, let me know.

I need to put this var inside a button. 
It's a button for a mobile website (in jquery), with the command "tel" (it uses the number beetween the { } to make a call):

```
< a target = "_blank " href = " tel:{{"telefono"}} " data-role="button" >
```

I don't find the right way to write the var in the button.

Can you help me?

Comment: is the button already created ?? or need to create the buttons too ??

Comment: The botton is created. 
It's only one, it will change only the var inside (i hope so!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this :

```
$('a[href~="tel:{{telefono}}"]').attr('href', 'tel:'+telefono);
```

If you want something more generic, that is you want to replace `{{telefono}}` in all your attributes `href`, you could use this :

```
$('[href~="{{telefono}}"]').attr('href', function(i, v) {
   return v.replace('{{telefono}}', telefono);
});
```

EDIT :

If you also want to change the content of the `a` element, you can do this :

```
$('[href~="{{telefono}}"]').attr('href', function(i, v) {
   return v.replace('{{telefono}}', telefono);
}).html(telefono);
```

Comment: About the first option, I tried 2 way:

-substitute var telefono = $(this).find('Telefono').text(); with $...

-add $... in the fuction. 

Both, they dont work.

About the second one, pretty cool.
I tried too, adding all the function you gave me...but it doesn't work. 
The button result empty, without any number inside.

I feel a bit frustrated.

Comment: This doesn't change the content of the button. I edited my answer for changing it.

Comment: Still, it doesnt work. I looks like inside the <a is written "telefono", not the value inside the var.

Comment: maybe should i put your function in a particular point?
do you need some other part of the html?